# ¿cómo guardar avance con base de datos ACCESS?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, ms-access-2013

Estoy haciendo un proyecto escolar sobre matemáticas, es un software didáctico donde el usuario se registra, hasta ahí todo bien, conecto una base de datos para almacenar los datos del usuario. Mi duda es ¿Cómo puedo guardar el avance que este usuario lleva? Cómo tal el software es un tipo curso que va por temas, entonces, mi intención es que sí el usuario ya ha completado el tema 1, cuando vuelva a ingresar con su cuenta las respuestas de los ejercicios a ese tema se mantengan resueltos.

Estoy en visual studio, con base de datos en access y lenguaje c#, Windows forms.

Comment: Tienes que crear el diagrama relacional. Crear las entidades y las relaciones entre ellas. Imagino que cuando dices "avances", te refieres a los temas que el estudiante ha estudiado. Entonces, ya sabes que un estudiante puede estudiar cero o más temas y un tema puede ser estudiado por cero o más estudiantes. Darte más información que esa, es hacer la tarea por tí. Saludos

Comment: Si estás comenzando en el mundo de desarrollo, sería mejor utilizar alguna tecnología más nueva

Comment: @Arriel no pretendo que alguien me haga la tarea así que gracias por la información!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.